# Saving Data to a Text File in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I've a functioning streamwriter that creates a text file and places the information I need in that file, but whenever I re-run the application the text file is created anew with the current values replacing the old. How do I ensure that previous data is saved in the text file with the new data being added on to it? Appending the data to the file seems to be the obvious route, but I'm just not sure how to incorporate the code for that into my program.

```
Dim CorpID, Fname, Lname, PreConf, ConfCost As String
        CorpID = txtCorpID.Text
        Fname = txtFirstName.Text
        Lname = txtLastName.Text
        If radNotAttending.Checked = True Then
            PreConf = ""
        Else
            PreConf = cmbCourses.SelectedItem.ToString
        End If
        ConfCost = decAttendCost.ToString("C")

        Dim wr As StreamWriter
        wr = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\Anon\Documents\SampleTextFile.txt")
        wr.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}, {4}", CorpID, Fname, Lname, PreConf, ConfCost))
        wr.Flush()
        wr = Nothing
```

Comment: Examine the help VS offers as you type methods.  StreamWriter has an overload to allow you to append.  Also please examine [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I do appreciate the help all the same. I figured that I would make some kind of misstep regarding the painfully specific guidelines stackoverflow has for question asking. However, given that I received the information I initially came here for, my endeavour was a success. And please don't misunderstand. I respect that the guidelines are simply there for efficiency, so they are worth reading and respecting. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another Overload of the StreamWriter Constructor.

Just use `wr = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\Anon\Documents\SampleTextFile.txt", true)`

You need [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example:

```
Using wr As new StreamWriter("C:\Users\Anon\Documents\SampleTextFile.txt",true)
    wr.WriteLine($"{CorpID},{Fname},{Lname},{PreConf},{ConfCost})
End Using
```

With `using`, `StreamWriter` is released when done with it, so when you click the button again, no `StreamWriter` is accessing the file and you can create another insatnce of `StreamWriter`without problems.

Comment: This works! Unfortunately, I must be missing something else. It only works once during a run of the program. If I click my button again to add more data, I get an IOException saying that the text file is being used by another process. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's because you are creating a new Steamwriter every time you push the button. You need to check if the Streamwriter is already created, if yes then just write with it.

Comment: so is it. Replace the code starting at Dim wr As Stream.....for my code and should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an overload of [the `StreamWriter` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) for exactly this purpose:

```
wr = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\Anon\Documents\SampleTextFile.txt", True)
```

The second parameter is:

> true to append data to the file; false to overwrite the file. If the specified file does not exist, this parameter has no effect, and the constructor creates a new file.

Comment: Oh, sorry you were quicker than me, I didn't see your answer. Quite nice is close the same answer lol

Comment: This works. However, If I trigger my button event again in the same run of the program to add more data, I get an IOException saying that the text file is being used by another process. Any suggestions?